How to run garbage collector on Bitbucket repository
My local repository is considerably smaller than the remote repo on bitbucket (~800 megabytes locally and 3.8 gigabytes on the remote). This is an issue because my repository is about to hit the 4GB limit, after which further commits will not be possible.
Let me clarify, the issue is not with the repo size, because locally, it's perfectly fine after running git gc, however, on the remote side it remains at its size. As specified in the documentation, I tried to create and reset a commit, but it does not seem to trigger garbage collection, are there any other ways to do that?

This is not a programming question; you are just asking how a certain web site works (BitBucket). The way to find that out is to read the instructions for using that web site. And in fact there is an instruction page about the very question you are posing: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/reduce-repository-size/ There is also info on contacting Bitbucket support if necessary.

@matt the question is about a tool devs use so I do believe it's suitable enough for this place:) Thanks for replying tho, and let me clarify my question so it's more obvious that I did my investigation before resorting to asking here. Have a good one!

Sure, we can agree to disagree. It just seems to me that there is nothing we can do for you here; this is between you and the Bitbucket folks.

Does this answer your question? How can I trigger garbage collection on a Git remote repository?

@Kolay.Ne it kind of does, seems like there are no ways to trigger gc apart from one's specified in BitBuckets documentation. Thanks for the hint!

How did you measure your "remote repo size"? Git does not do that.
